# jQuery targeting first div of kind within parent

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a class of .show-name to only the first instance of .field-diary-name within each parent block of .date-parent like in the example below:

Within my jQuery I've tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( ".date-parent .diarycontainer" ).first().find( ".film-diary-name" 
).addClass( "showname" );
});
```

This only adds the class to the first one in the first instance of the parent .date-parent and doesn't look through the second block.

```
    <div class="date-parent">
   <h3 class="cinema-h3">Tue 19 Feb 2019</h3>
   <div class="diarycontainer">
      <div class="film-diary-name show-name">Movie 1 (15)<span class="cert-15"> 
         </span> 
      </div>
      <span class="film-diary-times"><a href="#">7.40pm</a></span>
   </div>
   <div class="diarycontainer">
      <div class="film-diary-name">Movie 1  (15)<span class="cert-15"></span></div>
      <span class="film-diary-times"><a href="#">8.40pm</a></span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="date-parent">
   <h3 class="cinema-h3">Tue 19 Feb 2019</h3>
   <div class="diarycontainer">
      <div class="film-diary-name show-name">Movie 2 (15)<span class="cert-15"> 
         </span> 
      </div>
      <span class="film-diary-times"><a href="#">8.40pm</a></span>
   </div>
   <div class="diarycontainer">
      <div class="film-diary-name">Movie 2 (15)<span class="cert-15"></span> </div>
      <span class="film-diary-times"><a href="#">8.40pm</a></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `first()` gets the first element from the result stack.  It doesn't perform any logic other than that.

Answer (score 0):

`$( ".date-parent .diarycontainer" )` selects all `.diarycontainer` elements that are descendants of a `.date-parent` element. `.first()` then takes *only the first one* from that list. This will never be more than one element.

Rather than `first()` (function), I believe you want [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) (selector).

```
$(".date-parent .diarycontainer:first .film-diary-name").addClass("showname");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    $(".diarycontainer").parents('.date-parent').first().find( ".film-diary-name" 
).addClass( "showname" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:nth-of-type` selector to get only the first diarycontainer for each parent.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".date-parent .diarycontainer:nth-of-type(1)").find(".film-diary-name").addClass("showname");
});
```

```css
.showname { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-parent">
  <h3 class="cinema-h3">Tue 19 Feb 2019</h3>
  <div class="diarycontainer">
    <div class="film-diary-name show-name">Movie 1 (15)<span class="cert-15"> 
         </span>
    </div>
    <span class="film-diary-times"><a href="#">7.40pm</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="diarycontainer">
    <div class="film-diary-name">Movie 1 (15)<span class="cert-15"></span></div>
    <span class="film-diary-times"><a href="#">8.40pm</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="date-parent">
  <h3 class="cinema-h3">Tue 19 Feb 2019</h3>
  <div class="diarycontainer">
    <div class="film-diary-name show-name">Movie 2 (15)<span class="cert-15"> 
         </span>
    </div>
    <span class="film-diary-times"><a href="#">8.40pm</a></span>
  </div>
  <div class="diarycontainer">
    <div class="film-diary-name">Movie 2 (15)<span class="cert-15"></span> </div>
    <span class="film-diary-times"><a href="#">8.40pm</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```